# How to fix error "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFiles. Required permissions: "

Tags: google-apps-script

The problem is Error "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFiles. Required permissions: " is showing when "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"] is putted in appscript.js. But when i remove these oautScope, the error will show "Exception: The parameters don't match the method signature for isShareableByEditors. (line 15, file "Code")". I'm making my all file to to check "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers". I already enabled the drive API.

```
function test(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.isShareableByEditors(false);
  }
}
```

I expect all of my file on google drive will be "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Got it now, I changed the isShareableByEditors() to setShareableByEditors().

Correction:

```
function test(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setShareableByEditors(false);
  }
}
```